# What does "as of" date include?

Tags: family-law

Child support is deducted from my pay.

I have a court order in which the judge writes "There shall be no further amount of retroactive child support or ongoing child support as of July 31, 2016 payable by the Applicant to the Respondent."

I was paid on July 31, 2016. Should child support be deducted from this pay?

Answer (score 1):

No. "as of July 31, 2016" means that on July 31, 2016 nothing is owed on that date.